# Получаю SocketTimeoutException при использовании Retrofit 2 + OkHttp3

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

Имеется back-end с оооочень долгим запросом (70 секунд) к API. Работаю над back-end не я.
И имеется приложение, над которым работаю я.
Для работы с сетью использую OkHttp3, Retrofit 2 и GSON.
В билдере OkHttp проставил тайм-ауты с запасом (callTimeout, readTimeout, connectTimeout, writeTimeout) - 5 минут.
Запрос выполняется в среднем 70 секунд.
Но, несмотря на тайм-ауты, я все равно успешно отваливаюсь по SocketTimeoutException раньше 5 минут и даже раньше окончания выполнения запроса.